# Случайный выбор из нескольких анимаций

Tags: android, анимация, android-button

Работаю над собственной игрой. Есть кнопка, 3 анимации (anim1, anim2, anim3). Что нужно написать, чтобы по нажатии кнопки одна из этих анимаций случайно проигрывалась на кнопке?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте массив из трёх ваших анимаций (а вернее ссылок на них)

```
int[] anims = {R.anim.anim1, R.anim.anim2, R.anim.anim3};
```

С помощью рандома получаем случайное число от 0 до 2 и используем его как индекс для массива. По полученному индексу берём случайную ссылку на ресурс с анимацией.

```
Random r = new Random();
int index = r.nextInt(2);
int anim_res = anims[index];
```

Создаём анимацию передав методу `loadAnimation` контекст (`this`) и случайную ссылку на ресурс.

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, anim_res);
your_button.startAnimation(anim);
```

Вот так будет выглядеть слушатель

```
int[] anims = {R.anim.anim1, R.anim.anim2, R.anim.anim3};

(findViewById(R.id.button)).setOnClicklistener(new OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
Random r = new Random();
int index = r.nextInt(2);
int anim_res = anims[index];
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, anim_res);
((Button)v).startAnimation(anim);
}
});
```